# Identify Ring Isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can someone do a brief sanity check on my work on this:

Identify the following rings:

- **(a)** $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$

$x^2 = 3 \implies 4x^2 = 12$

$2x=-4 \implies 4x^2 = 16$

$12 \equiv 16 \implies 4 \in I$

$\cong (\mathbb{Z}/4)[x]/(x^2+1,2x)$

$2x = 0 \implies 2 \in I$

$\cong \mathbb{F}_2$

- **(b)** $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+i)$

$Z[i] \cong Z[x]/(x^2+1)$

$\therefore$ $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+i) \cong Z[x]/(2+x,x^2+1)$

kill $2+x$. $x \rightsquigarrow -2$

This maps $x^2+1 \rightsquigarrow 5$

kill $5$. $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+i) \cong Z[x]/(2+x,x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_5$

- **(c)** $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(6,2x-1)$

kill $6$. $\cong \mathbb{Z}/6[x]/(2x-1)$

$2x=1 \implies 6x=3 \implies 3 \equiv 0 \implies 3 \in I$

$\cong \mathbb{F}_3$

- **(d)** $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x^2-4,4x-5)$

$2x^2=4 \implies 16x^2 = 32$

$4x=5 \implies 16x^2 = 25$

$25 \equiv 32 \implies 1 \in I$

$\cong \mathbb{F}_1$

- **(e)** $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,5)$

kill $5$: $\mathbb{Z}/5[x]/(x^2+3)$

I can't see any other reductions so:

$\cong \mathbb{F}_5$

Comment: You should improve your exposition, I doubt someone will help you with that way of writting your work.

Comment: Iirc exactly the same question (or a very similar one) was posted a few days ago.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258751/identify-ring-isomorphisms

Comment: Only (b) is correct :(

Comment: ... any hints/tips?

Comment: I did post a similar version earlier. I didn't get good responses, and I've made progress in my own understanding so I redid most of my work, so I felt it warranted a repost.